# How do you show the limit of a function?

Tags: analysis, limits

Using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, how would you show that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{3+7x}{5+5x} = \frac{3}{5}$? The lecturer's definition and solution are nothing to shout about...

Comment: $\epsilon,\delta$ proofs are, in general, nothing to shout about. Instead, they are often intricate expressions of strategies for solving inequalities. You gave no details of what your lecturer did, but I'll venture to guess that whatever it was, indeed it was an intricate expression of a strategy for solving inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, you want to $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x| < \delta$, then

$$ \left| \frac{ 3 + 7x}{5+5x} - \frac{3}{5} \right| < \epsilon $$

We want to find a bound for $\left| \frac{ 3 + 7x}{5+5x} - \frac{3}{5} \right|$. Lets see

$$ \left| \frac{ 3 + 7x}{5+5x} - \frac{3}{5} \right| = \left| \frac{ 3 + 7x - 3x -3}{5(x+1)} \right| = \left| \frac{3x}{5(x+1)} \right| = \frac{ 3|x|}{5|x+1|} $$

Notice we want to control the $|x+1|$ term in the denominator. To do so, let us assume a priori that $\delta < \frac{1}{2} $. Then

$$ |x| < \frac{1}{2} \iff - \frac{1}{2} < x < \frac{1}{2} \iff \frac{1}{2} < x+1 < \frac{3}{2} \iff 2 > \frac{1}{x+1} > \frac{2}{3}$$

Therefore,

$$ \frac{ 3|x|}{5|x+1|} < \frac{ 2\cdot3 |x|}{5} = \frac{6}{5} |x|$$

and the last quantity is less than $\epsilon$ precisely if we choose $\delta = \frac{5}{6} \epsilon $. Since we assumed a priori that $\delta < \frac{1}{2}$, then the choice

$$ \delta = \min\left\{ \frac{1}{2}, \frac{5}{6} \epsilon \right\} $$

will work, and the proof is complete.

Comment: Do you not mean $|\frac{4x}{5(x+1)}|$ in an early step?

Comment: you are right! this is a typo. just change $3$ by $4$. The argument is still the same!

Comment: Ok, thanks so much!

Comment: you are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

There are a few common properties of limits that are quite useful to know. The one which is relevant here is the following:

If $f, g$ are continuous functions at the point $x_0$ and $g(x_0) \neq 0$, then $\frac{f}{g}$ is continuous at $x_0$ as well. This statement is the one you should prove using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit. Your specific example will follow.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the limit of a function $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ if and only if we can make
$$
\left|f(x) - L\right|
$$
small as $x \to a$. In our case, this is
$$
\left|\frac{3 + 7x}{5 + 5x} - \frac{3}{5}\right| = \left|\frac{5(3+7x) - 3(5 + 5x)}{5(5+5x)}\right| = \left|\frac{20x}{5(5+5x)}\right|
$$
So suppose now that you are given some $\varepsilon > 0$. Can you choose a $\delta > 0$ so that if $|x| < \delta$ you can make this term small?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method of proving $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L$ is to start from the inequality $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$ and attempt to solve that inequality for the quantity $|x-a|$. If you can get your solution into the form

$|x-a| < $(an expression involving only $\epsilon$ and constants *and not $x$*)

then you set that expression on the right hand side equal to $\delta$ and you are done. Unfortunately that is rarely possible, but it is a good starting strategy and very often leads to a complete proof. In this case, for instance, starting from

$$(1) \qquad \biggl| \frac{3+7x}{5+5x} - \frac{3}{5} \biggr| < \epsilon
$$

and simplifying and solving you can show that inequality (1) is *equivalent* to

$$(2) \qquad |x| < \frac{\epsilon}{4} |1+x|
$$ 
But the right hand side of (2) depends on $x$ so we are not yet done.

From this point you can observe that if $x < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ and if $x < 1$ then inequality (2) is true and so inequality (1) is true. In other words, if $x < \delta = Min\{\epsilon/4,1\}$ then (1) is true. QED.

Comment: Hmm, $x$ can be negative. Inequality $(2)$ doesn't hold, e.g., when $x=-0.24$ and $\frac{\epsilon}4=0.25$.